# Sharing a single module amongst workbooks?

Tags: excel, vba

What is the easiest way to share VBA code via a module, amongst different workbooks, without writing an addin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save it to your Personal Macro Workbook.

Click 'Record Macro' and select 'Personal Macro Workbook' from the Store macro in: drop-down.

Comment: The code needs to be saved in a way it an be used on different machines?

Comment: You could save a workbook containing the macros in a network location then then go to Home-Options-Advanced-General and put the path the "At startup, open all files in:" box. You coould make the workbook open as hidden so no-one can see it.